# How to configure global pattern for Net Core Test Explorer in visual studio code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a Net Core App and I need to make some test for Repository. Nevertheless I had some problem for Net Core Test explorer configuration. When I settle down the test project path, it couldnt be seen it in Test explorer tree. I did everything and followed all possible steps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-library-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0) without success. So, I'd like someone help to configure the Test Explorer global path given this project structure.

```
├── NetCoreApi
    ├── Controllers
    ├── Data
    ├── Models
    ├── NetCoreApi.Tests
    │   ├── NetCoreApi.Tests.csproj
    │   ├── UnitTest1.cs
    │   ├── Usings.cs  
    ├── NetCoreApi.csproj
    ├── NetCoreApi.sln
    ├── Program.cs
    ├── Properties
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── appsettings.Development.json
    ├── appsettings.json
    ├── bin
```

Thank you and have a nice day!